# How to import and use min.js and min.css in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, min.js

I am just converting html template into React.js component.

In html template, I have these reference links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
...
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js"></script>
...
```

I want to import and use these script and CSS files in a specific component.

Does anyone have some experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap

Comment: Hi, Penny! Thanks for replying. I checked and I tried but didn't work :(
I think the min.css file was in specific ```/css``` folder in the Html landing page template. I wanted to convert the landing page into the React.js component. So I think I should add the min.css files manually in my own React.js component? 
I made another one question for more details on a large scale here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359265/how-to-convert-html-js-css-template-to-react-js-component

Answer (score 0):

Install Bootstrap as node modules using npm command.

```
npm i bootstrap -S
```

It will add bootstrap dependencies to your package.json

Now, Import Bootstrap’s JavaScript by adding this line to your app’s entry point index.js or app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```